# The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am writing a service with POST request as:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Post")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string JStringCont)
    {
       ....
    }
```

Call to this service is given as:

```
    string jsonContent="[{some json}]"
    StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonContent);
    _oHttpClient = new HttpClient();
    _oHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
_oHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

response = _oHttpClient.PostAsync(requestURI, content).Result;
```

Service is clearly getting called through sending a parameter stringcontent.
I am not allowed to change the way service is getting called.

I can make changes in service itself.
POST method is not able to accept in the string format.
What can be the parameter which I can use over there in POST request which will accept stringcontent??

Currently it is giving me Error:

> Response: UnsupportedMediaType
>
> {"Message":"The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource.","ExceptionMessage":"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'String' from content with media type 'text/plain'.","ExceptionType":"System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException","StackTrace":"   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

Comment: Have you tried JsonResult?

Comment: Tried sending Content-Type header with value application/json?

Comment: I am not allowed to touch the code where service is getting called.. I want to make service as per it has got called

Answer (score 4):

You should allow `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` parses requests with `Content-Type: text/plain`. So on startup your application (in `Startup.cs` or `WebApiConfig.cs` file) you need -

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
```

config is `HttpConfiguration` object.

Comment: That did help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
> System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: No MediaTypeFormatter
> is available to read an object of type 'String' from content with
> media type 'text/plain'.

I was getting above error while doing `put` call with return type as string,

I used `putasync` with return type as Task string.

The issue got resolved, this should work for  you as well